# How to get PID of python process in windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pid

I want to run a python script from another python code in Windows. For this I am using "subprocess" module. Below are sample 2 python scripts.

`app.py` is as below,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

command = "python"
filename = "test.py"

args=[]
args.append(command)
args.append(filename)

output = subprocess.run(args)
```

and `test.py` is

```
import time

print("hello")
time.sleep(10)
```

When I run `app.py`, from subprocess `test.py` also runs. In ubuntu for both `app.py` and `test.py` separate PID s will be there.
But in Windows, I get PID of `app.py` but not of `test.py`.
I checked this command,

```
tasklist /v | FIND "test.py"
```

This gives empty result.
Can anybody help,
What should I do, so that I will get PID of `test.py`

Comment: What python version are you working with?

Comment: @Ron python 3.6

Comment: Add `import os; print(os.getpid())` to both script; I'm pretty sure that those should differ…